# groupadd: command not found

Tags: linux, permissions, user-groups

Cannot create a group in RHEL5. I get error `groupadd: command not found`.

Answer (score 22):

It seems that `groupadd` is the correct command: [RHEL5 admin](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel5/rhel5_administration/rhel5_s1-users-tools.html). `addgroup` is a debian specific commnad.

Are you logged in as root? `groupadd` is in `/usr/sbin` which, by default, is not in the path. run `echo $PATH` and see if `/usr/sbin` is there. Not that running it as non-root is very helpful: you require root access to add a group.

Comment: Or use the absolute path directly `/usr/sbin/groupadd <newgroupname>`

Comment: It's important how to switch to root before using ```groupadd``` command. ```su -``` hast path to ```sbin``` in ```PATH```.

Answer (score 0):

#### USING CENTOS 5.9

Make sure you have installed a FQDN (full qualified domain name), for example Centosbox.local. Then execute the following command as a user with sudo privileges:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Change the value of HOSTNAME from "whatever.unknown" to "whatever.local".

Reboot and enjoy using groupadd.

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for not finding the `groupadd` command is that you are trying to access it as a user that does not have read access to the program, which is typically found in `/usr/sbin/groupadd`. You will need to assume the root user's identity, either with `su` or `sudo` or logging in as root, and then you should find the command.

I'm using Cent OS 7 and I see that the program's permissions do not allow others to read it:

```
#>ls -l /usr/sbin/groupadd
-rwxr-x---. 1 root root 61336 Mar  6  2015 /usr/sbin/groupadd
```

As you can see, no permissions are set for others, which explains why querying the program as a user other than root results in not finding it.